# Does flat shading require this much vertex duplication?

Tags: webgl

I'm very new to WebGL (1.0) / OpenGL and I'm having trouble understanding vertices for flat and smooth shading -- and whether data optimization is even possible for flat shading in this situation:

Say I want to use an icosphere (2-subdivision). It has 42 points that define its 80 faces. Those point coordinates lie on a unit sphere.

Both flat and smooth-shaded icospheres will appear on the same screen.

With smooth shading, the normals will be identical to position vectors, so I get them for free. So I could use 42 `vec3` in one buffer for both `a_position` and `v_normal` and an index buffer of 240 `unsigned_byte` to access them for the object. Cheap!

But with flat shading, each *face would have its own normal,* which I think that means for WebGL 1.0 there will be three duplicate normals for each face. 80 faces means 240 `vec3` for `a_position` (with a lot of duplicate vectors) and 240 `vec3` for `a_normal` (two-thirds of which is just duplicate vectors). I can't see any other way to do this. On the other hand, I can add position and normal data together in the same buffer and I wouldn't need an index buffer.

I've got this working and it seems fast, but am I correct? Does it matter?

| Icosphere property | Count | Floats needed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Faces | 80 |  |
| Positions (smooth) | 42 | 126 (+240 indices) |
| Normals (smooth) | 42 | 0 (reuse positions) |
| Positions (flat) | 240 | 720 |
| Normals (flat) | 240 | 720 |

I feel like either I missed something in my studies or that this is just the reality of OpenGL and I should get used to it because it's inherently fast.

Comment: If webgl supports derivates, you may try using dFdx() and dFdy() and plug your normals into it. The derivate of the interpolated normal is constant. https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/dFdx.xhtml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct at arriving that for flat shading you'll have to duplicate positions. That is, because a vertex is the whole tuple of position, normal, and all the other attributes.

However this duplication has almost zero impact on rendering times. It adds some memory overhead, yes, but as far as the rendering process is concerned the same amount of data is transferred and incorporated into the rendering process. As a matter of fact the duplication of certain properties at a whole makes caching more predictable, since there's no data indirections (i.e. look up a different normal, depending on what face is rendered) involved. So that actually has theoretical performance gains.

You're doing it exactly right.

Comment: Thank you for your last comment. It makes me feel a bit less stupid at this stage.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, the most portable implementation of flat shading will require duplicating vertexes for each drawn triangle, which brings an overhead on memory usage (considerable in case of a complex geometry). Potentially, it may affect rendering performance as well, but this would depend on hardware (shouldn't be noticeable nowadays). That's what a basic WebGL 1.0 allows to do.

However, WebGL 2.0 and WebGL 1.0 with [OES_standard_derivatives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OES_standard_derivatives) extension gives another option - computing triangle normal directly in a Fragment Shader via derivatives:

```c
#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable
...
varying vec4 Position;
varying vec3 View;
...
void main()
{
  vec3 Normal = normalize (cross (dFdx (Position.xyz / Position.w), dFdy (Position.xyz / Position.w)));
  if (!gl_FrontFacing) { Normal = -Normal; }
  ...
  gl_FragColor = computeLighting (normalize (Normal), normalize (View), Position);
```

This requires per-fragment lighting (e.g. [Phong shading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phong_shading) instead of Gouraud shading). The shading result will NOT be exactly the same as duplicating vertexes and precomputing triangle normals on CPU, but visual effect will be the same - flat shading with distinguishable triangles.

Practically speaking, `GL_OES_standard_derivatives` is widely adopted.
In fact, GLSL 1.1 from desktop OpenGL 2.0 supported derivatives from the very beginning (no extension required) - it is only OpenGL ES 2.0 (and hence, WebGL 1.0) decided excluding it.

There are, however, some complains against derivatives implementations on various GPUs. Precise derivatives are expensive to compute, so that GLSL specifications allowed returning faster approximations instead - which was critical for an old graphics hardware. In practice, the method works mostly fine for flat shading, though one [OpenGL ES implementation (Qualcomm)](https://tracker.dev.opencascade.org/view.php?id=30136) has a weird behavior with flipped sign of returned values.

Here is, for example, a [research](https://tracker.dev.opencascade.org/view.php?id=30136) done for Android devices a couple of years ago (don't know if the same issues will be experienced in WebGL - web browsers might black-list broken implementations or apply some workarounds to known driver bugs):
[image: dfdx derivatives issues on Android]